# Product Alerts - Show Customers and Products

Tags: product, customer, ee-1.11

We are just trying to run a little script that returns the customers that are signed up for price alerts and what products they are watching

I tried this code

```
require_once('app/Mage.php');

$customer_id = 76046;
//$customer_id = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId();
$customer_price_alerts = Mage::getModel('productalert/price')
     ->getCollection()
     ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customer_id);
foreach ( $customer_price_alerts as $alert )
{
 echo $alert->getProductId();
}
```

however get error

Call to a member function getModelInstance() on a non-object in /var/www/html/app/Mage.php on line 432

anyone?

cheers
FireHorse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these lines at the start of file:

```
require_once('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app();
```